# Set Odoo's config settings on module installation

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have made my custom config settings in Odoo using `models.TransientModel` with implementing the `get_default` and the `set` function. The way I do it is the same like is shown in the answer for this question

[Set and get store data Odoo with TransientModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35366854/set-and-get-store-data-odoo-with-transientmodel)

When the module installed, the settings is empty. How to have a default value of that config settings on install?

I've tried using the `init` function.

```
def init(self, cr):
    config = self.pool.get("ir.config.parameter")
    config_value = {
        "value": "randomaddress@gmail.com",
        "key": "myapplication.email_address"
    }
    config.create(cr, uid, config_value, context=None)
```

It didn't work.

Comment: Try `__init__` instead.

Comment: There is also documentation on custom settings here: http://ludwiktrammer.github.io/odoo/custom-settings-odoo.html

Comment: Have you found solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by getter and setter method as below :

```
class ClassName(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'res.config.settings'

    key = fields.Char()
    value = fields.Char()

    @api.model
    def get_default_key_values(self, fields):
        return {
            'key': "myapplication.email_address",
            'value': "randomaddress@gmail.com",
        }

    @api.multi
    def set_key_values(self):
       self.ensure_one()
       ICP = self.env['ir.config_parameter']
       ICP.set_param('key', self.key)
       ICP.set_param('value', self.value)
```